# How can I fix my alert dialog in kotlin compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-alertdialog

I' ve been making a dictionary app for a while and I added that users can create own dictionaries on my app. I show users dictionary on the screen and users can delete their dictionaries whatever they want. so I am trying to make alert dialog for this because I want users not to delete their dictionaries when they press the delete icon directly. An alert dialog will appear on the screen and there should be two buttons such as cancel and accept in that alert dialog. If the user presses accept, that is, if he wants to delete, I want the dictionary to be deleted.

However, the problem is that it is difficult to implement this in compose and in the codes I wrote because I encountered many problems for some reason, whereas it should have been easy. What I did in my codes is that if user clicks delete icon `onDeleteClick` works and `showAlertDialog` becomes true in `onDeleteClick`. When true, it goes inside the top if block and calls the alert dialog component. When the alert dialog compo is called, `CustomDialogUI` opens. I send two parameters to `CustomDialogUI`, one is a `showAlertDialog` mutablestate that controls the opening and closing of the alert dialog, and the second one is `deleteDicState` if the user says allow in the alert dialog that opens, `deleteDicState` becomes true and if `deleteDicState` is true, the deletion must occur.

Since `deleteDicState` is false the first time, it does not delete, but when the alert dialog opens for the second time and I say delete, it deletes it for some reason. How can i solve this problem help.

**my code**

```
@Composable
fun CreateYourOwnDictionaryScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    viewModel: CreateYourOwnDictionaryViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {

    val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()
    val state = viewModel.state.value

    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    val context = LocalContext.current
    val showAlertDialog = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val deleteDicState = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }



    if(showAlertDialog.value){

        Dialog(onDismissRequest = { showAlertDialog.value = false }) {
            CustomDialogUI(openDialogCustom = showAlertDialog,deleteDicState)
        }

    }



    Scaffold(
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                backgroundColor = bar,
                title = {

                    androidx.compose.material3.Text(
                        text = "your dictionaries",
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                        color = Color.White,
                        fontSize = 22.sp
                    )

                },
                navigationIcon = {
                    IconButton(onClick = {
                        navController.navigate(Screen.MainScreen.route)
                    }) {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Filled.ArrowBack,
                            contentDescription = "Go Back"
                        )
                    }
                }

            )

        },

        floatingActionButtonPosition = FabPosition.Center,
        floatingActionButton = {
            FloatingActionButton(
                onClick = { navController.navigate(Screen.CreateDicScreen.route) },
                backgroundColor = bar,

                ) {
                Icon(Icons.Filled.Add, "fab")
            }
        }
    ) {

        Box(modifier = Modifier.background(MaterialTheme.colors.background)) {


            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(16.dp)
            ) {


                LazyColumn(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                ) {
                    items(state.dictionaries) { dictionary ->

                        CreateYourOwnDictionaryItem(
                            dictionary = dictionary,
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .clickable {
                                    navController.navigate(Screen.MyWordsScreen.passDicId(dictionary.uid))
                                },

                            onAddClick = {
                                navController.navigate(
                                    Screen.MakeYourDictionaryScreen.passDicId(
                                        dictionary.uid
                                    )
                                )
                            },

                            onDeleteClick = {


                                if(deleteDicState.value){
                                    viewModel.onEvent(
                                        CreateYourOwnDictionaryEvents.DeleteDictionary(dictionary)
                                    )

                                    scope.launch {
                                        val result = scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
                                            message = "dictionary is deleted",
                                            /*actionLabel = "Undo",*/
                                            duration = SnackbarDuration.Short
                                        )
                                    }
                                }



                            },
                            onEditClick = {

                                navController.navigate(
                                    Screen.UpdateOwnDictionaryScreen.passDicIdAndDicName(
                                        dictionary.uid,
                                        dictionary.creationTime,
                                    )
                                )

                            }

                        )
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    }

}

@Composable
fun CustomDialogUI(
    openDialogCustom: MutableState<Boolean>,
    deleteDicState : MutableState<Boolean>
    )  {


    Card(
        //shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium,
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
        // modifier = modifier.size(280.dp, 240.dp)
        modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp, 5.dp, 10.dp, 10.dp),
        elevation = 8.dp
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color.White)
        ) {

            //.......................................................................
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_baseline_warning),
                contentDescription = null, // decorative
                /*contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
                colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(
                    color = bar
                ),*/
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(top = 35.dp)
                    .height(70.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth(),

                )

            Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
                androidx.compose.material3.Text(
                    text = "Warning !",
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(top = 5.dp)
                        .fillMaxWidth(),
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2,
                    maxLines = 2,
                    overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
                )
                androidx.compose.material3.Text(
                    text = "Are you sure that your previously created dictionary will be deleted?",
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(top = 10.dp, start = 25.dp, end = 25.dp)
                        .fillMaxWidth(),

                    )
            }
            //.......................................................................
            Row(
                Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(top = 10.dp)
                    .background(bar),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround
            ) {

                TextButton(onClick = {
                    openDialogCustom.value = false
                }) {

                    Text(
                        "Not Now",
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                        color = Color.Black,
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 5.dp, bottom = 5.dp)
                    )
                }
                TextButton(onClick = {
                    openDialogCustom.value = false
                    deleteDicState.value = true
                }) {
                    Text(
                        "Allow",
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.ExtraBold,
                        color = Color.Black,
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 5.dp, bottom = 5.dp)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }



}
```

I cannot call the `CustomDialogUI` in `onDeleteClick` . If I call it, it gives the following error `@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function`.

**for example like this**

**`CreateYourOwnDictionaryScreen`**

```
 onDeleteClick = {

                                Dialog(onDismissRequest = { showAlertDialog.value = false }) {
                                    CustomDialogUI(openDialogCustom = showAlertDialog,deleteDicState)
                                }
....
```

**I cannot call like this.**

So I call it outside of `onDeleteClick`. or directly in `CustomDialogUI` if the user presses the delete button, I cannot delete it there because I can't access viewmodel and dictionary there

**for example like this**

**`CustomDialogUI`**

```
  TextButton(onClick = {
                    openDialogCustom.value = false
                  
                    viewModel.onEvent(
                        CreateYourOwnDictionaryEvents.DeleteDictionary(dictionary)
                    )

                    scope.launch {
                        val result = scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
                            message = "dictionary is deleted",
                            /*actionLabel = "Undo",*/
                            duration = SnackbarDuration.Short
                        )
                    }
                
                }) {
                    Text(
                        "Allow",
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.ExtraBold,
                        color = Color.Black,
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 5.dp, bottom = 5.dp)
                    )
                }
            }
```

**I cannot call like this.**

Answer (score 1):

Passing `MutableState`s as composable parameters is considered a bad practice, you should pass raw values and callbacks instead. In your case, you can implement it like this:

```
@Composable
fun CreateYourOwnDictionaryScreen() {
    val showDeleteDialogForItem = remember { mutableStateOf<DictionaryItem?>(null) }

    showDeleteDialogForItem.value?.let { itemToDelete ->
        DeleteDialog(
            onDeleteConfirm = {
                viewModel.onEvent()
                showDeleteDialogForItem.value = null
            },
            onCancel = { showDeleteDialogForItem.value = null },
        )
    }
    
    ...
    items.forEach { item ->
        CreateYourOwnDictionaryItem(
             onDeleteClick = { showDeleteDialogForItem.value = item }
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun DeleteDialog(
    onDeleteConfirm: () -> Unit,
    onCancel: () -> Unit,
) {
   ...
   Button(onClick = onCancel) { Text("Cancel") }
   Button(onClick = onDeleteConfirm) { Text("Delete") }
}
```

Comment: it looks good but when I apply your code there is a problem. you declare val showDeleteDialogForItem and you have set this val value to null after that, so android studio gives an this error " Val cannot be reassigned" . Shouldn't it var ?  when I do var it gives this error "Null can not be a value of a non-null type MutableState<OwnDicEntity?>"

Comment: and why didn't you use onCancel and onDelete in DeleteDialog. When I type the same thing, it gives the following warning " The expression is unused" . 
And finally, you said it's bad practice to use mutableState, but haven't we used mutableState here again? and why would you explain the bad practice?

Comment: Yeah, it should've been `showDeleteDialogForItem.value = null`, that will work, sorry. Both `onCancel` and `onDeleteConfirm` are used in `DeleteDialog` as onClick callbacks of the buttons, so I don't see what you mean.

Comment: And yes, we used mutableState here, it's not a bad practice to use it but to pass it to another composable function. So instead of `@Composable fun X(checkedState: MutableState<Boolean>)` you should do `@Composable fun X(isChecked: Boolean, onCheckedChange: (Boolean) -> Unit)`

Comment: I understand the button part, but when the user presses delete, the dictionary clicked on showDeleteDialıgItem is transferred and nothing happens after that, so the DeleteDialog composable is not triggered.

Comment: When user presses delete, you update `showDeleteDialogForItem` with the item that should be deleted. That triggers recomposition and since `showDeleteDialogForItem.value` is not null anymore, the code inside `let` will be executed which will show the dialog. Does it not work for you like that?